# What is the current version of the corda accounts library?

Tags: corda

I cannot create a new AccountInfo. I have set up the corda accounts library to version 1.0-RC01 and am running into:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/contracts/states/AccountInfo

Answer (score 0):

Accounts SDK is still at the development stage. There is no guarantee of functional stability. We also did not release any official "versions" with the account SDK.